# Mysql: How to create a column which is the difference between a column in a Table & another column in a View

Tags: mysql, create-table, create-view

In the database 'college2' there are 3 TABLES:'student, course & enrolment', and one(1) VIEW:'enrolment_status', which is created using the following command:

```
CREATE VIEW enrolment_status AS
SELECT code, COUNT(id)
FROM enrolment
GROUP BY code;
```

Explain command for 'course,enrolment and enrolment_status' results in:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN course;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code          | char(8)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name          | varchar(90) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| max_enrolment | char(2)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.09 sec)

mysql> explain enrolment;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | char(6) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| code  | char(8) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> explain enrolment_status;
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code      | char(8)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COUNT(id) | bigint(21) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.18 sec)
```

'max_enrolment' column in 'course' TABLE is the maximum allowed # of student for each course, say 10 or 20.
'count(id)' column in 'enrolment_status' VIEW (not table) is actual # of students enrolled in each course.
'id' column in 'enrolment' TABLE is the student id enrolled in a course.

HERE'S MY QUESTION:
I want to have the '# of seats left' which is the difference between 'max_enrolment' column and 'count(id)' column.
'#of seats left' can be a stand alone table or view or a column added to any of the above tables. How can i do this:

I tried many commands including the following,

```
CREATE VIEW seats_left AS (
    SELECT course.code, course.max_enrolment - enrolment_status.count
    FROM course, enrolment_status
    WHERE course.code = enrolment_status.code);
```

...which gives me the  following error message:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'enrolment_status.count' in 'field list'

mysql> SELECT*FROM enrolment_status;
+----------+-----------+
| code     | COUNT(id) |
+----------+-----------+
| COMP9583 |         7 |
| COMP9585 |         9 |
| COMP9586 |         7 |
| COMP9653 |         7 |
| COMP9654 |         7 |
| COMP9655 |         8 |
| COMP9658 |         7 |
+----------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT code, max_enrolment FROM course;
+----------+---------------+
| code     | max_enrolment |
+----------+---------------+
| COMP9583 | 10            |
| COMP9585 | 15            |
| COMP9586 | 15            |
| COMP9653 | 12            |
| COMP9654 | 10            |
| COMP9655 | 12            |
| COMP9658 | 12            |
+----------+---------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------+---------------------+
| code     | max_enrolment - cnt |
+----------+---------------------+
| COMP9583 |                   9 |
| COMP9585 |                  14 |
| COMP9586 |                  14 |
| COMP9653 |                  11 |
| COMP9654 |                   9 |
| COMP9655 |                  11 |
| COMP9658 |                  11 |
+----------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Comment: Create a count first before you proceed to the next process

Comment: Is the count is the field name of your table `enrolment_status`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use an acronym for in the view.

```
CREATE VIEW enrolment_status AS
SELECT code, COUNT(id) count
FROM enrolment
GROUP BY code;
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
CREATE VIEW seats_left AS (
SELECT course.code, course.max_enrolment - enrolment_status.count
FROM course, enrolment_status
WHERE course.code = enrolment_status.code);
```

If you cannot change the view, then you must use the exact same name in the query:

```
CREATE VIEW seats_left AS (
SELECT course.code, course.max_enrolment - enrolment_status.'count(id)'
FROM course, enrolment_status
WHERE course.code = enrolment_status.code);
```

Comment: Thanks 'clinomaniac' for taking your time and suggestion. I actually tried both versions above: 'enrolment_status.count'  and 'enrolment_status.count(id)'. Both giving the same error message. I am now trying to see if i get any result using php commands, instead of just mysql command lines.

Comment: Did you try to change the view? Using "()" in the column name is not ideal.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, i will do it now!

Comment: Also..I see that the data types are different. One is CHAR and one is BIGINT. You should make those consistent as well.

Comment: @'Clinomaniac', Using 'count' without (id) gives the following:   ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'COUNT' in 'field list' .    I guess the reason is that the parameter to be counted: number of students (id)s taking the same course, have to be specified.

Comment: Are you talking about creating the view?

Comment: In 'enrolment_status' view, the course code: 'code' is a combination of letters+ integers, so i had to use CHAR. The #of students enrolled in the course 'code' is a 2 digit#. I was surprised that the system assigned 'bigint(21)' to count(id), which i think is a: 21 digit big integer.

Comment: You can use a cast in your view to make sure both are integers. Where is the error now? Were you able to create the view with the alias?

Comment: If i can somehow create a column: "seats_left=max_enrol  - count(id)", it wouldn't matter much if it is a new 'view' or a new column in an existing table.

Comment: Did you create the view with the alias? 
CREATE VIEW enrolment_status AS
SELECT code, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM enrolment
GROUP BY code;

Comment: I am not familiar with 'cast' and 'view with alias' (due to be new in coding). I have to do some research to learn how they work.

Comment: I believe the issue you are facing is because the column name in the view enrolment_status has (). If you have such names, then things can get complicated. That's why I would recommend recreating the enrolment_status view and use an alias for the column count(id) as counts so then the column name will not have ()s.

Comment: Yes, i created the view with the command exactly as yours, I didn't know it is called 'view with alias'. Now i know.!

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW enrolment_status AS SELECT code, COUNT(id) AS counts FROM enrolment GROUP BY code;

Comment: Its not called anything. I just mean that the view with using an alias for that column. What does "EXPLAIN enrollment_status" return now?

Comment: I don't know how reliable the following source is, they have used COUNT () syntax also.   https://www.w3resource.com/sql/creating-views/create-view-with-count-sum-avg.php,

Comment: mysql> SELECT*FROM enrolment_status;
    +----------+-----------+
    | code     | COUNT(id) |
    +----------+-----------+
    | COMP9583 |         7 |
    | COMP9585 |         9 |
    | COMP9586 |         7 |
    | COMP9653 |         7 |
    | COMP9654 |         7 |
    | COMP9655 |         8 |
    | COMP9658 |         7 |
    +----------+-----------+
    7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @clinomaniac in your last query you should change `'enrolment_status.count(id)'` to `enrolment_status.\`count(id)\``. But it's better to use an alias as you already suggested in your first query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.`code`,max_enrolment - cnt from
(select `code`, cnt from
(select count(1) as cnt,`code` from enrolment_status
GROUP BY `code`) as a) as a

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT code,max_enrolment from course) as b
on a.`code` = b.`code`
```

You can change `left join` to `right join`

Comment: Reds, your code 'partly' works. In my original question above,  I have posted 3 tables: max_enrolment, enrolment_status, and table that i get using your code (which should equal to the difference between max_enrol and enrol_status), e.g: in the first row max_enrol = 10, enrol_status = 7, the result should be 10-7=3, but the code gives out 9. I couldn't figure out why it does that. BTW, I re-wrote your code using single quotes ('code') , which didn't work, and i realized that i had to use backticks (`code`) instead. Tks+Rgds